# Home network setup with two access points

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, ethernet

In a couple of months I'm moving to a new place (ground level appartement) with a bit of a peculiar network setup and I'm seeking some advice on how to set it up.

There is cable internet which enters the house in the basement, where the cable modem is located together with two ethernet connections. One leads to the front of the appartement, the other leads to the back.

Right now the owner simply plugs in the cable leading to the back, where the living room is located, and he has a wifi access point in the living room.
But I'll be making a home office in the front of the house, needing wifi there too. The problem is that simply adding an access point doesn't cut it (current owner tried this), there is a patio in between the front and back of the appartement, so the wifi signal would have to cut through an outside wall, onto the patio, and then once more through a wall to get inside again.

It's probably feasible to buy a couple of access points, and route the signal all around the hallway, bedrooms etc into the home office. This feels a bit cumbersome, and is kind of my "Plan B".

But I was hoping that the extra ethernet connection in the front of the house would make a better "Plan A" possible, I'm not sure how though.

Is it possible to use some small 2-point ethernet hub or switch in the basement, connecting both the front and the back of the house, adding a wifi access point at both places all while begin on the SAME wifi network?
I'm pretty sure it'll be possible while creating two networks, but I'd rather not do that (I'd rather not switch networks and lose e.g. a skype connection when walking around the house, or constantly switch networks at certain places in the house) Or are there other ways to cope with that?

It's a bit hard to explain the situation without actually being there :), I hope I made it clear enough though, and someone can help me point out what my options are.

(In case this matters, I think we have seven-ish devices which connect to the network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution should work well.  You can get a cheap switch for the basement, and plug in both ethernet cables, and a third to the modem.

This will make both the front and back connections live.  You can then put an AP in both positions, connecting via their LAN ports.  The APs should have the same SSID.

There are two caveats that you'll want to be sure of:

1. Only one of the three devices is a DHCP server.  This is either the modem, or one of the APs
2. Choose non overlapping channels.  To make this easy, choose two from 1, 6, or 11.

Answer (score 1):

In that case where the wireless signal of a router is being blocked by thick walls, etc. It is better to use powerlines (if and only if your house is using the same circuit breaker).

Powelines that has wireless adapter on it can act as an AP itself so you can set its channel width and channel to avoid overlapping as what [Paul](https://superuser.com/users/89018/paul) mentioned.
Other than that, it is just using a cable to be located on the front of the house for an access point to be connected.